# Стоит ли разделять речь на абзацы, если присутствует действие персонажа?

Tags: прямая-речь, абзац

*— Может быть, - произнёс Олег, откашлявшись. Он ловко спрятал ключи в заднем кармане. Он знал, что Евгений приходил вчера вечером, но не хотел рассказывать об этом семье. — В любом случае, его давно никто не видел.*

Единственное, что меня смущает, это справочник Розенталя:

Если между двумя репликами одного и того же говорящего лица находится текст от автора, то ни этот текст, ни последующая прямая речь в отдельные абзацы обычно не выделяются:

— Не получается что-то у меня с проводом, — ответил мастер. Он немного подумал и добавил: — Придётся всё делать заново.

**Но если в тексте от автора описывается действие говорящего лица, то и авторский текст, и последующая прямая речь выделяются в абзацы**:

— Формула эта может иметь и другой вид, — пояснил профессор.

Он неторопливо подошёл к доске, взял мел и написал что-то новое для нас.

— Вот это и есть другой вариант, — сказал он.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я бы написал так:

> — Может быть, — произнёс Олег, откашлявшись; ловко спрятал ключи в
> задний карман. Он знал, что Евгений приходил вчера вечером, но не
> хотел рассказывать об этом семье. — В любом случае, его давно никто не
> видел.

В таком виде действие Олега становится частью предложения-пояснения после тире и абзацировано быть не может. А следующее предложение, где он знал и хотел, уже не содержит действия, поэтому перенос его на следующий абзац также не требуется никакими правилами.

Если же строго ваш текст писать по правилам, то абзацирование неизбежно и в конце лучше добавить авторские слова, чтобы обозначить принадлежность последней реплики:

> — Может быть, - произнёс Олег, откашлявшись.
>
> Он ловко спрятал ключи
> в заднем кармане. Он знал, что Евгений приходил вчера вечером, но не
> хотел рассказывать об этом семье.
>
> — В любом случае, — добавил мужчина, — его давно никто не видел.

Comment: Разумеется, есть разные варианты, которые обойдут указанное правило. Но этот текст я выдумал в качестве примера. Мне важно понять, как писать правильно именно с такой конструкцией. Важно узнать, допустимо ли писать так в художественной литературе.

Comment: Я понимаю ваше желание. Нет, правило, на мой взгляд, можно только обойти переформулировкой, сменой пунктуации, игрой с местоимениями. "Он" в вашем примере действительно просится на красную строку, и в таком случае в последней реплике придётся добавить авторские слова, чтобы реплика не казалось произнесённой другим персонажем, а не Олегом. Я сейчас дополню ответ этим вариантом.

Comment: Спасибо. Касаемо возможного варианта - вы там использовали контекстуальный синоним "мужчина", что является моветоном)

Comment: Я сейчас посмотрел, как писал [Чехов](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1146/p.3/index.html) (Каштанка). У него там в примере разделений на абзацы нет:

— Ладно, ладно! — сказал хозяин, зевая. — Надо жить мирно и дружно. — Он погладил Каштанку и продолжал: — А ты, рыжик, не бойся... Это хорошая публика, не обидит. Постой, как же мы тебя звать будем? Без имени нельзя, брат.

Comment: Почему моветоном? Если читателю пока не открыты автором другие характеристики (типа "доктор", "хирург" или иное), то характеристика по полу и возрасту незаменима, разве нет? Можно, конечно, крутиться и использовать слова типа "собеседник", но не всегда такое уместно.

Comment: За это меня ругал преподаватель в вузе (бывший редактор и корректор в издательстве). Я потом смотрел примеры в классической литературе и в бестселлерах - там никогда не использовали контекстуальные синонимы. Очень тонкая грань, когда надо показать читателю характеристики какого-то персонажа от лица повествователя. Типо "Вот же несносный мальчишка!", - подумал Северус. Здесь контекстуальным синонимом будет "мальчишка", потому что Северус в своей голове использует для идентификации фамилию "Поттер". Олег никогда не будет называть себя мужчиной (ведь в примере речь идёт от его лица).

Comment: Хм. Я учился на писательских курсах, где наши тексты проверяли также редакторы и корректоры, и ни разу не получил замечания за контекстные синонимы. Возможно, зависит от жанра. В языковой прозе встречаются сплошь и рядом, вот я открыл томик Славниковой — и тут же аж два контекстных синонима, "изверг" и "знаменитость": «Замечательно, Роман Петрович! Вы просто волшебник!» — звонко ответила знаменитость, и в круглых глазах ее, обрамленных свалявшимися темными ресницами, блеснули слезы. «Что-то не так?» — забеспокоился изверг. «Ой, Роман Петрович, ну совсем немножко…».

Comment: *"Олег никогда не будет называть себя мужчиной (ведь в примере речь идёт от его лица)"* — нет, в примере повествование идёт от лица автора, и именно автор назвал Олега мужчиной.

Comment: Ну, откровенно говоря, автор в качестве примера выбран не самый лучший. Даже ваш пример подтверждает, как тяжело читать такой текст. Мне пришлось половину главы прочитать, чтобы понять, о каких людях идёт повествование.

Comment: Повествование идёт от лица Олега. Это же в тексте видно: "Он знал, что...". Как кто-то другой может читать мысли Олега? В то же время Олег не знает, что думают или чувствуют в данный момент другие люди. В качестве простого примера откройте любую главу про Гарри Поттера. Если повествование идёт от лица Гарри, то Северус всегда будет Снейпом, Рон Уизли всегда будет Роном (а не "рыжим", "мальчиком" и т.д.). Гарри всегда будет "Гарри". Гермиона всегда будет Гермионой. При этом в тексте будут только мысли и чувства самого Гарри - потому что повествование идёт от его лица. От того, как видит других

Comment: Автор выбран самый лучший, топовый в своём жанре, мастер слова и филолог :) И то, что вам пришлось прочитать половину главы, говорит как раз в пользу жанра. Вероятно, дело всё-таки в жанре; я согласен, что в жёстком бестеллере такое вряд ли будет уместно (хотя надо проверять, я никогда не задумывался над вопросом и потому не отслеживал, использует ли автор такие синонимы).

Comment: Третье лицо — это не лицо Олега, это лицо Автора. Есть несколько режимов повествования от третьего лица, в том числе такой, при котором Автору известны все мысли героя (повествование от ограниченного третьего лица), и называть персонажа Автор может как угодно.

Comment: Что касается Гарри Поттера: вот я открыл случайную книгу из семи, задал поиск по "мальчику" и нашёл тут же два места с этим контекстным синонимом: 1) "— Пойдем погуляем, — шепнул Рон Гарри, — подальше от Перси. <...> Мальчики спустились по лестнице и очутились в гроте, полном цветущих розовых кустов..." 2) "Гарри шел по коридорам и думал о сне. Сон был как будто наяву, совсем как тот, от которого Гарри проснулся на Тисовой улице. Мальчик перебрал в уме все детали: не забыл ли чего?"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вам спасибо за указание на (возможный) моветон.